# Why does enterFullScreenMode cause drag and drop to fail?

Tags: appkit, chromium-embedded

I've search high and low but have not found any mention of this issue. When I enter full screen mode (calling enterFullScreenMode on my NSView), my application stops receiving mouse drop events. I can click on a draggable object but I can't drag it to another container. It works fine, except when I'm in "full screen mode".

I'm running in Chromium Embedded Framework, so specifically, I stop receiving OnDragEnter CEF events (https://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/index.html). Has anyone experienced this kind of behavior? Any ideas on what could be causing it?

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, it's this command that was disabling drag and drop:
[[(AppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setLevel:1000000];

Apparently the value 1000000 is invalid, which results in this peculiar side effect.